# Ferromagnet $\leftrightarrow$ paramagnet at Curie temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, phase-transition, critical-phenomena, ferromagnetism

I think it's like this: $\, m=\tanh\left(\frac{Bμ}{k_bT}\right)$. If now the temperature decreases, then $\mu$ increases, until it flattens out ($\tanh$ function). Is the a point where $m$ flats out, the critical point, because then all spins are aligned, and thus the paramagnet becomes a ferromagnet? If the temperature increases, $\mu$ goes to zero, and thus the spins are all random (=paramagnet)?

Comment: What are $\beta$ and $\mu$?

Comment: The argument of your tanh doesn't make sense. Is it meant to be something like $\mu_B B / kT$ (with $\mu_B$ the Bohr magneton)?

Comment: $\mu$ is the magnetic moment

Comment: But $m$ too seems to indicate magnetic moment. You should check your notation. Anyway, the critical point is at zero external field.

Comment: m is the magnetisation, $m= \mu * 1/N * (\sigma_1 + .... + \sigma_N)$

Comment: As it stands this looks like Curie's law for paramagnets, so there's no ferromagnetism involved. Or did you get this expression from some mean field theory and the $B$ field isn't an external one but an internal effective field that itself depends on $m$?

Comment: I was just trying to clarify for myself why a ferromagnet becomes a paramagnet above $T_c$, because that was said in my lecture (statistical thermodynamics). Somewhere else in my course we've seen the Curie law